# How to get updated objects after flush() in the same transaction (Hibernate/ Spring boot)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a list of ~10 000 objects.

I am trying to call an ***mysql update query (procedure)*** and then to get the updated objects inside same transaction.
Can this be achieved ?

When I call a ***delete statement + flush()***, hibernate retrieves me correct objects (deleted objects are missing)
But when I try ***update statement + flush()***, hibernate retrieves me the initial unchanged objects.

```
@Transactional
void test() {
  //...
  em.createQuery("delete from StorefrontProduct sp where sp in (:storefrontProducts)")
                    .setParameter("storefrontProducts", storefrontProductsToDelete)
                    .executeUpdate();

  // example
  em.createQuery("update StorefrontProduct sp set sp.orderIndex=0 where sp.id=90")
                            .executeUpdate();
  em.flush();

  //Simple JPA query
  List<StorefrontProduct> result = repository.findAllByPreviousOrderIndexIsNotNull();

  //additional code....
}
```

After running the code from above and putting a breakpoint after findAll call, provided objects from 1-st query were deleted and flushed, but the update query was not flushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is known counterintuitive behaviour of Hibernate.

First of all, `em.flush()` call might be superfluous if flush mode set to `AUTO` (in that case Hibernate automatically synchronises `persistence context` (session-level cache) with underlying database prior executing update/delete queries).

**Delete and successive Select case**:

- you issues `delete` then `select`, since `select` does not see deleted records anymore you do not see deleted records in resultset, however if you call `findById` you may find deleted records.

**Update and successive Select case**:

- you issues `update` then `select`, when processing resultset Hibernate sees  both records stored in database and records stored in `persistence context` and it assumes that **`persistence context` is a source of truth**, that is the reason why you see "stale" data.

There are following options to mitigate that counterintuitive behaviour:

1. do not perform direct updates, use "slow" `find/save` API instead
2. either `detach` or `refresh` stale entities after direct update, `em.clear()` may also help, however it completely cleans up `persistence context`, which might be undesirable

Comment: @andrey-b-panfilov
Unfortunately, I can not implement solution 1. as there are 10k objects, and it would generate thousands of queries. 
Tried solution 2. , but seems that after clearing persistent context using em.clear(), it still loads old data. Only solution which worked was to commit the data and only after to do the select. 
So there is no any way to get the flushed updated data before commit ?

Comment: @MichaelBat well, typical scenarios are: 1. there are two transactions, however, since you tell you do not see deleted records, it is not a case. 2. there are two entity managers backed up by a single JDBC connection, that could be a case. How do you get `em` in your test case? Would you mind providing complete code (and repository code as well)? 3. `executeUpdate` actually updates nothing and DB state changes due to another code. Have you checked that `executeUpdate` returns positive integer? 4. There is external cache which influences on result. Complete code required.

Comment: @andrey-b-panfilov just did some additional tests. It worked. Thank you a lot. 
I am getting em using `@PersistenceContext` annotation. 
I remarked that if I used JPA `deleteAll()` instead of `em.createQuery(delete ..)`, it was retrieving me old data. I find this weird, but yeah, now it works.